# non-modifiable value within vector?

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have the following data structure:

```
struct file{
    char  name[MAX_FILE_NAME];
    char  data[BLOCK_SIZE - MAX_FILE_NAME]
};

struct disk{
    vector<file> current_file;
};
```

When I try to modify something say in index 0 of whatever disk I've created like so:

```
disk new_disk;

new_disk.current_file[0].name = "new name";
```

I get the error that `expression must be a modifiable |value`

I feel like it's late and I just can't seem to understand something simple... but why won't that work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assign arrays like that, e.g.

```
char foo[500];
foo = "this won't work";
```

You have to use a function like `strcpy`

```
strcpy(new_disk.current_file[0].name, "new name");
```

`strncpy` would be safer, and `std::string` would be even safer.